# Error: The requested module is not installed: filepicker

Tags: ee2, file-uploads

I'm using EE version 3.0.2. I created a channel but when I try to upload a file it gives the following error: 
**"Error: The requested module is not installed: filepicker"**.

[image]

[image]

I am unable to find any solution to resolve this as I'm very new at using expression engine. Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: @fmz I'm facing the exact same issue as your "Member Group unable to upload images to channel entries". Sometimes I get blank popup like yours and sometimes it shows me that error I just posted. Did you get any solution?
I can't comment there because of low reputation.

Comment: I believe you need the full paid version (with license) of EE3 to use FielPicker

Comment: I've a purchased version of EE 3.0.4, I has got the same problem, file upload dialog box doesn't have functionality in it @DonRhummy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved in the latest release `3.0.4`

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to drop a quick update, this is a confirmed bug and the EE devs are currently working on a fix.